# Clustat command not found error in python script

Tags: python, bash

Hi I am trying to create a script using python to log on to a server and to check the status of the cluster by running a clustat command. When I do this I get the following error:
/bin/sh: clustat: command not found
As I understand it, it's not able to run the command as this is a non standard bash command that is being used. I was hoping someone would have some ideas to get around this to get it work.

Below is the method used to run the command:(I have antoher method to ssh onto the system it works fine)

```
def run_cmd(command):
"""Function for running command on the system."""
proc = subprocess.Popen([command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
return out
```

This is where it seems to go wrong. I know the run_cmd method works as I am able to use it with other commands:

```
run_cmd("clustat >> out.txt")
return ""
```

Comment: Does `clustat >> out.txt` work  in the terminal?

Comment: If I am logged into the server it will work fine. That's what has me confused, because as far as I understood it, using subprocess to execute commands should be executing them as though you are on the system

Comment: No, `subprocess` won't magically connect and log you into a remote system.

Comment: Sorry I should mention that I am already connected to the system at this point using paramiko

Comment: `subprocess` runs the commands **locally**. You will have to use `paramiko`'s SSH client to run commands on the remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess` runs the commands **locally**.

You will have to use `paramiko.SSHClient` to run commands on the remote machine.

```
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.connect(host='some_host', username='username', password='password')

ssh_client.exec_command('clustat >> out.txt')
```